Artikel bei Abstraktum
Automatisch, ohne nachzudenken, würde ich es so schreiben:
1. Das ist pure Liebe.
2. Das ist eine unerwiderte Liebe.
3.  Das ist reine Frechheit.
Wenn ich aber beginne, darüber nachzudenken, werde ich verwirrt. Warum habe ich das ohne den bestimmten Artikel geschrieben, wenn Abstrakta eben den bestimmten Artikel erfordern? Und hier sind sie noch mit einem Adjektiv versehen, was wohl ein weiterer Grund dafür wäre, den bestimmten Artikel zu verwenden, da das Substantiv durch das Adjektiv präzisiert wird. Ich glaube, die Version mit dem bestimmten Artikel wäre korrekt, aber wie steht es bei (1) und (3) mit der artikellosen Variante?
Bei (2) hat man eigentlich mit dem Gleichen zu tun wie bei (1) und (3) und trotzdem habe ich automatisch den Artikel benutzt... Wenn ich mir jetzt diese Inkonsequenz zu erklären versuche, kommt mir das Folgende in den Sinn: Das ist eine Abkürzung von "das ist ein Fall / ein Beispiel einer unerwiderten Liebe", also empfindet man hier die Liebe nicht mehr als ein Abstraktum, sondern als eine konkrete Beziehung zwischen zwei konkreten Leuten (nehmen wir mal Werther und Lotta aus Goethes Roman).
Nachdem ich mir über (2) überlegt hatte, neige ich von nun an jedoch, auch bei (3) den unbestimmten Artikel hinzuzufügen. Das artikellose (3) klingt für mich jetzt falsch.
Was aber (1) betrifft, habe ich nach wie vor nicht das Gefühl, dass dies falsch sein könnte... Wenn ich mir das erklären versuche, sehe ich das nicht so sehr wie ein Beispiel einer konkreten Beziehung wie bei (2), sondern vielmehr als... Ich weiß nicht, wie ich das bezeichnen könnte.. wie eine Eigenschaft,  immer noch wie ein Abstraktum. Dann sollte ich mich daran stören, warum also nicht der bestimmte Artikel. Und jetzt kommt mir als Erklärung: An sich schon, sollte der bestimmte Artikel sein, aber die Kraft der prädikativen Funktion, und mit dieser haben wir in diesem Satz zu tun, ist demgegenüber überrangig. Deshalb verlangt das prädikativ benutzte Substantiv keinen Artikel, obwohl es ein Abstraktum ist.
Ist meine Denkweise da richtig? Wie sieht es wirklich aus?

Das Deutsche ist so verliebt in seine Artikel, dass es sogar die Abwesenheit eines solchen als "Artikel" (nämlich den "Nullartikel") bezeichnet. "Keinen Artikel" gibt es also nach manchen Auffassungen eigentlich gar nicht :)

Ja, deine Denkweise ist so größtenteils richtig. Das entscheidende Konzept hier ist die Zählbarkeit. "Eine Liebe" ist zählbar, wie "ein Glas", es kann also "diese Liebe und jene Liebe" geben, während "Liebe", wie "Wasser" nicht zählbar ist.
Du meinst zwar

Deshalb verlangt das prädikativ benutzte Substantiv keinen Artikel, obwohl es ein Abstraktum ist.

, aber Abstrakta sind im deutschen generell nicht zählbar. Aber sie werden häufig mit bestimmten Artikeln genutzt, die nicht zwischen zählbar und nicht zählbar unterscheiden. Wir bevorzugen halt normalerweise "Die Liebe ist blind" vor "Liebe ist blind." Einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung gibt es hier nicht wirklich.
Was ist "das" genau?
Ich glaube, bei deinen Sätzen gibt es zwei Faktoren, die deine Analyse stören. Der eine ist das "das": "Das" kann sich im Deutschen auf alles mögliche beziehen, von einem sachlichen Nomen aus dem Satz davor, über ein Ding, auf das du zeigst, und den ganzen Satz davor bis zu einem Sachverhalt, über den gesprochen wird.
Es hilft, sich zu überlegen, was dieses "das" sein kann, mit Sätzen wie:

Dass er sich so aufopfert, ist pure Liebe. 
Was ich am liebsten mag, ist [?eine] unerwiderte Liebe. 
Dieses Gefühl ist [?eine] Liebe. 
Die Liebe in der Bibel ist [eine] pure Liebe.

Satz 2 zeigt, was du mit der konkreten Beziehung meinst. Man kann das Konzept der unerwiderten Liebe nicht mögen, sagt man aber "eine unerwartete Liebe", meint man eine ganz bestimmte. Und weil es davon mehr als eine gibt, ist das zählbar. Satz 3 zeigt aber, dass eine konkrete Beziehung nicht ausreicht. Es ist zwar "dieses Gefühl", aber das ist nicht "eine Liebe", sondern "Liebe".
Satz 4 zeigt, was ein Artikel noch bedeuten kann. Man drückt damit aus, dass es verschiedene Konzepte/Begriffe "Liebe" gibt. Und das ist dann wieder zählbar. Deswegen heißt es "eine andere Liebe", aber nur selten "andere Liebe".
"pur" und "rein" mögen keine Artikel
Der zweite Faktor sind die Worte "pur" und "rein". Wendet man sie auf Abstrakta an, so bedeuten sie so etwas wie "ausschließlich" oder "und nichts anderes".
Wenn du etwas aus "purer/reiner Boshaftigkeit" tust, dann tust du ausschließlich aus Boshaftigkeit, und nicht aus anderen Gründen. Das sagt nicht aus, das deine Boshaftigkeit besonders "rein" oder "unverfälscht" ist.
Das funktioniert dadurch, dass du ja auch sagen könntest, es sei "etwas Liebe und etwas Einbildung". Hier willst du bildlich aber sagen, das Gefühl sei "Liebe", ohne Spuren von anderem.
Das kann aber rein von der Bedeutung her nur bei Abstrakta funktionieren. Denn "eine Liebe und eine Einbildung" funktioniert anders. Sagst du "eine reine Liebe", so ist die Liebe rein, aber du bekommst nicht die Aussage, es sei auschließlich Liebe.
Hier kommt die Unzählbarkeit ins Spiel. Wenn die Worte unzählbar sind, dann ist das bildlich wie mit zwei Flüssigkeiten: Sie lassen sich mischen. Wenn sie zählbar sind, geht das bildlich nicht.
Warum nicht der bestimmte Artikel?
Hier ist eine Analogie mit echten Dingen hilfreich. Wir wissen ja schon, dass bei Abstrakta bestimmt und unbestimmt nicht so einen großen Unterschied machen. Bei echten Dingen aber schon:

Das ist [das] Wasser.

Mit "das" ist es ein konkretes Wasser. Das Wasser ist schon bekannt. Ohne "das" ist Satz 5 eine Aussage, dass es sich um Wasser und keine andere Flüssigkeit handelt. Mit was hat ein Satz wie

Das ist [die] Liebe.

wohl normalerweise mehr gemein?


Wenn ich aber beginne, darüber nachzudenken, werde ich verwirrt.

Zunächst eine Vorbemerkung: wir alle haben ein Sprachzentrum - und das beherrscht fehlerlos die Sprache, die wir gelernt haben. Probleme fangen üblicherweise erst an, sobald man dieses Sprachzentrum mit dem Verstand zu korrigieren versucht. Da kommen dann Sachen wie das Politikerdiktum "die Menschen in unserem Land" heraus, weil das Sprachzentrum jedes deutschen Muttersprachlers hier "Leute" setzen will, vom Verstand aber - zum Zwecke der Anmenschelung - niedergebrüllt wird. Sprache wird, um Karl Kraus zu paraphrasieren, erlebt, nicht gedacht.
Die folgenden Ausführungen können deshalb - wenn man sich nur lange genug darauf konzentriert - als grundfalsch "erkannt" werden.
Abstraktum ohne oder mit bestimmtem Artikel
Das drückt ein Konzept aus.

Das ist pure Liebe.
Das ist die reine Frechheit.

Das heißt, daß "das" (was auch immer damit gemeint ist), diesem Konzept von "purer Liebe" (oder auch "reiner Frechheit") entspricht. Das ist das "Abstraktum" im eigentlichen Sinn. Eine solche Formulierung wird verwendet, wenn etwa Aussagen wie (Vorsicht, Kalenderspruch):

Liebe ist stärker als der Tod.
Die Frechheit siegt.

in den Raum gestellt werden. Damit ist nicht ein konkret bestehendes Gefühl zwischen zwei konkreten Menschen gemeint, sondern das Gefühl schlechthin, unabhängig von den Akteuren. Ob man solche Dinge so allgemein überhaupt sagen kann, sei dahingestellt, die Grammatik allein sagt wenig über Richtigkeit oder Abgeschmacktheit eines Satzes aus.
Ob man beim Hantieren mit Abstrakta den bestimmten Artikel verwendet oder nicht, ist wohl hauptsächlich eine Frage des Geschmacks, nicht der Grammatik. In den beiden Kalendersprüchen oben könnte man auch die bestimmten Artikel weglassen bzw. hinzufügen ohne an der grundlegenden Beliebigkeit der Aussagen etwas zu ändern. Tendenziell wird der bestimmte Artikel aber eher weggelassen, wenn die Abstraktheit betont werden soll: "Schuld und Sühne" sind abstrakte Konzepte, "die Schuld und die Sühne" klingt eher wie der Titel einer juristischen Abhandlung über bestimmte Rechtsbegriffe.
Eine weitere Einschränkung betrifft den Kasus: die oben gemachte Unterscheidung gilt natürlich nur für den Nominativ! Andere Fälle müssen schon deshalb mit dem Artikel markiert werden, weil dies oft die einzige Möglichkeit im Deutschen ist, den Kasus kenntlich zu machen:

dem Wahren, Guten, Schönen

Ohne Artikel könnte das genausogut ein Akkusativ oder Nominativ Plural sein.
Abstraktum mit unbestimmtem Artikel
Das drückt ein konkretisiertes Beispiel/Exemplar eines Abstraktums aus, das aber implizit als beispielhaft für eine Kategorie vorgestellt wird:

Das ist eine unerwiderte Liebe.

Die "unerwiderte Liebe" ist das Konzept, wie oben, allerdings wird ein konkretes Exemplar - das, was sich hinter dem "das" verbirgt - beschrieben, indem es mit diesem Abstraktum verglichen wird. Implizit wird gesagt, daß es auch andere Beispiele, Arten, oder Ausformungen desselben Abstraktums gibt:

Das (eine) ist eine unerwiderte Liebe, das (andere) aber auch.

oder auch:

Sowohl dies wie auch das ist eine reine Frechheit.

